# Estimate error using MATLAB (least squares)

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I have the equation ln(c)=-1/2k^2 * z^2, where y = ln(c), x = z^2 and a = -1/2k^2.

I want to estimate the `a`, so:

```
a = polyfit(z.^2, log(abs(c)), 1)
```

Because I have the (initial) equation c = exp(-z^2/2k^2), from above I am  founding two values for `a` and now I want to estimate k (k1), so I do:

```
k1 = sqrt(-1/2*a(1))
```

Now, I want to predict c and error using values of k1 and z. So, I do:

```
c_predict = polyval(a,z)
c1 = exp((-z.^2)/2*k1^2)
error = c_predict - c1
```

Or just:

```
c1 = exp((-z.^2)./2*s1^2)
error1 = c - c1
```

What is right?

```
error = c_predict - c1
```

or

```
error = c - c1
```

?

Comment: Question is not on topic for SO. It seems to me to be more appropriate for [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into the norm command:

relative least squares error = `norm(y-y',2)/norm(y)`

y is your original signal and y' is the signal your measuring the error of.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html)